# What is the gantt chart "type" in Anychart?

Tags: reactjs, anychart

I'm relatively new to React and I am trying to build a gantt chart using Anychart.

It seems pretty straight forward for other chart types, but I cannot work out what 'chart type' is needed for a gantt chart.

For example, I took the data from their site and just tried to plot it on a gantt chart:

```
function GanntChart() {

  const myData = [
    { name: 'Root', children: [
      { name: 'Parent 1', children: [
        { name: 'Child 1-1', value: 150000000 },
        { name: 'Child 1-2', value: 45000000 },
        { name: 'Child 1-3', value: 3200000 }
      ] },
      { name: 'Parent 2', children: [
        { name: 'Child 2-1', value: 55000000 },
        { name: 'Child 2-2', value: 10600000 },
        { name: 'Child 2-3', value: 5200000 }
      ] },
      { name: 'Parent 3', children: [
        { name: 'Child 3-1', value: 21000000 },
        { name: 'Child 3-2', value: 9000000 }
      ] }  
    ] } 
  ]


  return (
    <>
      <AnyChart
        type="gantt-chart" 
        data={myData}
        title="Simple gantt chart"
      />
    </>

  )
```

As you can see I have tried "gantt-chart" and a bunch of other variations.

Does anyone have an example of a basic gantt built in React?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried "ganttProject"? That's how it is referenced [in the docs](https://api.anychart.com/anychart#ganttProject).

Comment: Amazing, works perfectly.  Thanks for the link too, searched for ages!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build a lot of different chart types with anychart-react, and due to the complexity of Gantt Charts, the preferred approach is an embedding of vanilla JS into the React application.

Here is the example

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";

//Importing a pure JS function
import { gantChart } from "./chart/anychartGantt";

function App() {
  //Create a data variable
    //Later you have to populate it with some actual data
  const myData = [];

  //Calling useEffect to get chart at the right time
  useEffect(() => {
    //Making a chart instance
    const chart = gantChart("chart_container", myData);

    //Preventing duplicate renders
    return () => chart.dispose();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="chart_container"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//This is the main function of a Gantt Chart. 
//All of the appereance settings should be done here

export const gantChart = (container, data) => {
  // Creates Gantt project chart.
  var chart = anychart.ganttProject();
  chart.data(data, "as-tree");
  chart.title("Creating Gantt chart with React and Anychart");
  chart.container(container);
  chart.draw();
  return chart;
}
```

In the attached GitHub repository, you can find this full [example of using Anychart with React and Vanilla JS](https://github.com/Bepely/anychart_react).

If you have found direct React implementation important for you, feel free to contact us at support@anychart.com.